# ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (3 for 0) when adding like, favorite and inappropriate button to microposts with make_flaggable gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I want to add like, favorite and inappropriate button to microposts.

User can like a micropost only one time. But also user who likes the micropost can click the favorite button.

When I tried that in rails console I've an error.

**Error**

```
 irb(main):002:0> micropost=Micropost.first

 ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (3 for 0)
 from /Users/tanerkoroglu/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/make_flaggable-99297edddfec/lib/make_flaggable.rb:22:in `make_flaggable'
 from /Users/tanerkoroglu/Desktop/Wishpere2/app/models/micropost.rb:9:in `<class:Micropost>'
from /Users/tanerkoroglu/Desktop/Wishpere2/app/models/micropost.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:457:in `load'
```

**micropost.rb**

```
  make_flaggable :like, :inappropriate, :favorite
```

**user.rb**

```
 make_flagger :flag_once => true
```

**create_make_flaggable_tables.rb**

```
class CreateMakeFlaggableTables < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def self.up
   create_table :flaggings do |t|
     t.string :flaggable_type
     t.integer :flaggable_id
     t.string :flagger_type
     t.integer :flagger_id
     t.text :reason

     t.timestamps
  end

   add_index :flaggings, [:flaggable_type, :flaggable_id]
   add_index :flaggings, [:flagger_type, :flagger_id, :flaggable_type, :flaggable_id], :name => "access_flaggings"
  end

 def self.down
     remove_index :flaggings, :column => [:flaggable_type, :flaggable_id]
     remove_index :flaggings, :name => "access_flaggings"

     drop_table :flaggings
 end
end
```

**create_microposts.rb**

```
class CreateMicroposts < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
    create_table :microposts do |t|
     t.text :content
     t.references :user, index: true, foreign_key: true

     t.timestamps null: false
 end
     add_index :microposts, [:user_id, :created_at]
 end
end
```

**add_flaggings_count_to_microposts.rb**

```
 class AddFlaggingsCountToMicroposts < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
     add_column :microposts,:flaggings_count, :integer
   end
 end
```

**add_flaggings_count_to_users.rb**

```
  class AddFlaggingsCountToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
       add_column :users, :flaggings_count, :integer
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all `make_flaggable` method doesn't accept any parameter as mentioned in the source code [here](https://github.com/medihack/make_flaggable/blob/99297edddfec3ed2fadc90808d3033c68c58d772/lib/make_flaggable.rb#L22) and that's why you see 3 for 0 argument error.

You don't have to pass any argument to `make_flaggable` in your model.

micropost.rb

```
make_flaggable
```

By default, the model becomes flaggable by any other model.

If you want it to be flaggable by models where it has been marked as flagger. Then you can restrict micropost be flagged only by those models which are marked as flagger.

micropost.rb

```
make_flaggable :once_per_flagger => true
```

So for your model, don't pass any parameter to `make_flaggable`.

Comment: Thanks @imechemi. Can you guide me how I can add the like parameter ? in controller  with "micropost.flaggings.with_flag(:like)" ? Is it true?